# Java Serialization/De-serialization giving null object references

Tags: java, serialization, null

I'm working on a group project and we've run into a problem with the serialization part of our software. We have the class protocol:

```
    import java.io.Serializable;

    import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

    public class Protocol implements Serializable{


        private static final long serialVersionUID = 3474882407641871963L;
        private int state;//0 = logged out 
        //1=logged in waiting for search 
        //2= search query sent
        private String output;
        private TableModel searchResults;

        public Protocol(int state){
            this.output = "";
            this.state = 0;
            this.searchResults = null;
        }

        public void setState(int s) {
            this.state = s;
        }

        public void setOutput(String o) {
            this.output = o;
        }

        public void setSearchResults(TableModel results) {
            this.searchResults = results;
        }

        public String getOutput() {
            return this.output;
        }

        public int getState(){
            return this.state;
        }
        public TableModel getSearchResults(){
            return this.searchResults;
        }


    }
```

We also have the SearchResult class:

```
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
    import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

    /**
     * An implementation of the TableModel interface that utilises a List of DataRow objects to
     * store the data.
     * 
     * @version 13/03/2014
     * @author Jake Darby
     * 
     * @see DataRow
     * @see TableModel
     */
    public class SearchResult implements TableModel 
    {
        private final List DATA;
        private static final int NUM_COLUMNS = 8;
        private final int NUM_ROWS;

        /**
         * Constructor that generates a SearchResult object from a set of Results of a query to the 'products' table
         * 
         * @param data The results of an SQL query of the 'products' table
         * @throws SQLException
         * 
         * @see ResultSet
         */
        public SearchResult (ResultSet data) throws SQLException
        {
            super();
            DATA = DataRow.generate(data);
            NUM_ROWS = DATA.size();
        }

        /**
         * Constructor creates an empty TableModel
         */
        public SearchResult()
        {
            super();
            DATA = new ArrayList();
            NUM_ROWS = 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() 
        {
            return NUM_ROWS;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() 
        {
            return NUM_COLUMNS;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) 
        {
            switch(columnIndex)
            {
            case 0:
                return "ID";
            case 1:
                return "Name";
            case 2:
                return "Price";
            case 3:
                return "Pack Quantity";
            case 4:
                return "Quantity in Stock";
            case 5:
                return "VAT";
            case 6:
                return "Order Date";
            case 7:
                return "Expiry Date";
            default:
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) 
        {
            switch(columnIndex)
            {
            case 0:
            case 3:
            case 4:
                return Integer.class;
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 6:
            case 7:
                return String.class;
            case 5:
                return Boolean.class;
            default:
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) 
        {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) 
        {
            DataRow row = DATA.get(rowIndex);
            switch(columnIndex)
            {
            case -1:
                return row.getPrice();
            case 0:
                return row.getID();
            case 1:
                return row.getName();
            case 2:
                return String.format("£%d.%02d", row.getPrice()/100, row.getPrice()%100);
            case 3:
                return row.getPackQuantity();
            case 4:
                return row.getQuantity();
            case 5:
                return row.getVAT();
            case 6:
                return row.getOrderDate() == null ? "N/A" : row.getOrderDate();
            case 7:
                return row.getExpiryDate() == null ? "N/A" : row.getExpiryDate();
            default:
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) 
        {/*No implementation*/}
        @Override
        public void addTableModelListener(TableModelListener l) 
        {/*No implementation*/}

        @Override
        public void removeTableModelListener(TableModelListener l) 
        {/*No implementation*/}

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            String result = "";
            for (int i = 0; i
```

The problem arises when we write the Protocol class over a client-server socket connection. The issue is that the TableModel object in the Protocol class becomes null at some point in the serialization/de-serialization process, and nothing we have done has yet fixed this.

We have so far tried:

- implementing Serializable in SearchResult (I don't believe that it should be necessary due to TableModel implementing Serializable)

- changing the TableModel field variable to a SearchResult field variable in Protocol

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Don't post your entire code. Take your time and create [minimal example](http://www.sscce.org/) we could use to reproduce your problem. There is also a chance that while creating such example you will figure out your problem yourself.

Comment: Your `SearchResult` class isn't `serializable`

Comment: @NickHolt: OP has tried implementing Serializable in SearchResult as given in the points

Comment: I don't see how you're serializing the class. Are you using ObjectOutputStream?

Comment: Is the serialization/deserialization happening in the same JVM?  Given you've set the `serialVersionUID` on `Protocol` it's possible that you have two different versions of the class (if you're using 2 JVMs).  One version of the class without the `searchResults` field being used on serializing side and another version of the class with the `searchResults` field being used on the serializing side, hence the field remains `null`

Answer (score 1):

This code correctly serializes and de-serializes the object:

```
//write out the object
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("out.myobj");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
Protocol p = new Protocol(4);
p.setState(5);
oos.writeObject(p);
oos.close();

//read it in
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("out.myobj");
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
Protocol x = (Protocol)ois.readObject();
ois.close();
System.out.println(x.getState());
```

Output:

> 5

In this case, it's something with how you write the object to the stream.

FYI: TableModel is an interface that does **not** implement Serializable. Implementing Serializable is *necessary* here only for Protocol. If you're instead writing out the class implementing TableModel, then that one needs to implement Serializable too.

See the docs:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html

Answer (score 0):

**("protocol Controller") I think you should implement and use this**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

@Named(value = "protocolController")
@SessionScoped
public class Protocol implements Serializable
```